# how to open a new window from a JSP file?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I need to open a new window from a jsp file. In a JSP file, I take in an input from the user and then send it as an argument to a java method which returns me back the url as a string. I then need to open this in a new window. How do I do that? Below is the jsp file(send_product.jsp) for your reference.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="products.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%
    productManager pm= new productManagerImpl();
    String myUrl= null;


    if (request.getParameter("product_id") != null) {

        // get the paramter
        String product_id = request.getParameter("product_id");

        try {

            //myUrl has the url. Have to open this in a new window
            myUrl = pm.getUrl(product_id);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Insert</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="wheat">
        <h4 align="right">Send Product</h4>
        <hr color="red"/>
        <br/><br/>
        <a href="index.jsp">Index</a>
        <form action="send_product.jsp" method="post">   
            <% if (myUrl  != null && !myUrl.equals("")) {%>
            <%= myUrl%>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>

            <%
                }
            %>

            <table width="75%" align="center" >
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Please enter the information below and click "<b>Submit</b>"
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <fieldset title="info">
                            <table border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        * Product ID:
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <input type="text" size="20" maxlength="70" name="product_id">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            </table>
                            <hr />

                            <div align="center">
                                <input type="submit" name="saveInfo" value="Submit">
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to let your JSP print the following line of JavaScript whenever the URL has been received:

```
<script>window.open('<%= myUrl%>', 'YOUR_WINDOW_NAME');</script>
```

This way JS will open a new window/tab.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete question, putting Java code inside JSP like that is a [poor practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files). Be warned!

Comment: but I want to open the url which is in the string myUrl(this string catches the return value of the method getUrl). Suppose the method returns www.google.com, I want to open google.com in a new window.

Comment: Oh you're processing the form submit inside the same JSP?! I'll update the answer.

Comment: yes I am. I know it is not the best way to do it. I am also getting the response back successfully. I don't know how to open the  url in the string in a new window